# Infusionsoft REST API with salesforce

Tags: rest, infusionsoft

I am trying to access Infusionsoft data from salesforce trigger. I am able to access the data after authorizing the IS app manually by a user vai VF page/ UI. I want to skip this. I want to get the data with automatic app authorization.

Requirment:
1. SF trigger-->2. Call IS REST API to Authorize-->3. Get Code --> 4. Call IS REST API Token url--> redirecct_url / Access IS CRM data for manipulation

But after step 2 it is redirecting me to IS login/ authorize page and then redirecct_url

As I am calling from code I cant access redirected url and its query string params.

Any suggestion /Help it is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We had similar situation in our case. We've decided to authorize access manually once, save access token in our database and refresh it regularly using a cron job (as access token expires in 24 hours - this value changes from time to time). Thus, you'll need to get access token manually only once per Infusionsoft application, using saved token for all following requests.